# rEfind shows multiple Ubuntu choices

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac, refind

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Macbook with the intention of dual booting Ubuntu and OS X Sierra. First time after installing Ubuntu, rEfind didn't work and every time I turned on my Mac it jumped straight into Ubuntu. I solved this problem by holding the Option (alt) key while turning on. Then I reinstalled rEfind in OS X.

However, every time I turn on my Mac now, rEfind shows 3 different choices for booting Ubuntu. It looks like this:

```
1) EF\ubuntu\fbx64.efi from EFI

2) EF\ubuntu\mmx64.efi from EFI

3) EF\ubuntu\grubx64.efi from EFI
```

I am totally new to Linux, so I have no idea which one to choose. Does anybody know which one is the "right" one? I would appreciate help very much.

I am using a Macbook Pro 13" 2012 with OS X Sierra and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu recently renamed `MokManager.efi` to `mmx64.efi`, and added `fbx64.efi` (which just launches GRUB through a new path). rEFInd recognizes MokManager and handles it in a special way, and ignores some known-redundant boot loaders, but this renaming results in both of these programs appearing when they aren't necessary or should be handled in new ways.

I've fixed this problem and released it in rEFInd 0.10.6 -- but please use the latest version available (currently 0.10.7), since 0.10.6 had an unrelated bug that could cause it to hang on some systems.

After you install that and reboot, the `fbx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi` options should disappear from the OS list and a new key icon should appear on the second row for `mmx64.efi` (although that's a tool related to Secure Boot, so it's useless on a Mac, since Macs don't support Secure Boot).

Note, however, that the `refind-install` script will normally install an EFI filesystem driver for ext4fs, which will normally enable you to launch Linux kernels directly. The result will be one icon to launch GRUB and another to launch your Linux kernel directly. These are redundant, but they also launch Ubuntu in different ways, so there is some value to having them both available -- if one method stops working, the other may continue to work. If you don't want two options to be on the menu, though, you can remove one by deleting the EFI filesystem driver or by using `dont_scan_volumes`, `dont_scan_dirs`, or `dont_scan_files` in `refind.conf`. See the rEFInd documentation for details, and especially:

- http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html
- http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html

Comment: Hi Rod, thanks for your work on this it's really awesome. It would be great if you can update the docs for refind to reflect this rename as it's taken me several hours to figure out why I didn't have MokManager.efi on Ubuntu 17.04!