# What is EFI/Ubuntu/mmx64.efi?

Tags: uefi

Long story short: I switched to ubuntu 16.04 with `UEFI` mode. I booted in `UEFI`, I created the `EFI` partition, but after the instalation my `BIOS` couldn't see ubuntu. I used Boot Repair (with the "try ubuntu without installation" option) and now it works great! But, when the [grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW1y5.jpg) shows up, I get this `EFI/Ubuntu/mmx64.efi` option. What is it? If i choose it, my laptop will freeze with a black screen. I should worry about it?

Oh, and another little question (please don't get angry about it) - I'm using a 128Gb SSD for `/` and 1Tb HDD for `/home`. I got 25 seconds from the moment I turn on the laptop to the actual desktop environment. With windows 10 (I don't have dual boot) I remember I had under 15 seconds. Again, should I worry about it?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/903207/refind-shows-multiple-ubuntu-choices  or was mokmanager.efi  or for UEFI keys & ask separate question or search on slow boot.